# Creating object in bulk and then serialize them

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

model:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Product,...)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

view:

```
pobj = Product.objects.get(user=request.user, id=id)
nimg = int(request.data['numofimg'])
for i in range(nimg):
    image = request.data[f'image{i}']
    obj = ProductImage.objects.create(post=pobj, image=image)

pobjs = Product.objects.all()

serialerize = ProductImageSeriailzer(pobjs, many=True)
# it would be better if pobjs only have newly created objects (in above for loop)
```

Is their any efficient code for the same?
Here number of queries will increase with number of image
How can i reduce them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reduce the number of database writes, but you could do a `bulk_create` of your objects.

```
pobj = ProductImage.objects.get(user=request.user, id=id)
product_images = [ProductImage(post=pobj, image= request.data[f'image{x}']) for x in range(int(request.data['numofimg']))]
ProductImage.objects.bulk_create(product_images)
pobjs = Product.objects.all()
```

This will reduce some code, but under the hood `bulk_create` is also doing a `CREATE` for every passed object.

---

By the way you are passing `Product` objects in to the `ProductImage` serializer. Also you have a typo in `ProductImageSeriailzer` and `serialerize`. It should be `ProductImageSerializer` and `serializer`.

Comment: So number of sql queries won't be less :(